# How can I successfully evade the Police at higher wanted levels?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've been having some trouble evading the police when they start calling the helicopters out to spot me. Two stars and below it's pretty easy to flee in a car and either avoid the cops altogether or duck into some alleyway until they lose you.

Helicopters however, always seem to spot me when there's something (a building, a container, etc) between me and the helicopter. Sneaking or going into cover doesn't seem to help.

So what's my best bet for evading the all-seeing helicopter at higher wanted levels?

Comment: Shoot them down :p

Comment: I was able to hide under an overpass with my car up against a wall and lost a 3 star rating.

Comment: @Ryan Check you out, rebel

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Head immediately for the nearest train track then find the nearest tunnel.

They show on the map as light grey lines. Tunnels show as a darker grey.

The helicopters can't find you in tunnels and in most cases if you get a good run down the tracks you'll have lost the cars too. On the off chance a cop car does make it into the tunnel with you it shouldn't be too hard to dispatch them as they can't surround you any more.

After that it's just a case of making sure you don't get hit by a train. They're very loud when approaching so that shouldn't be too hard either and then you're home free.

This is my tried and trusted method that has worked successfully right up to 5 stars.

Answer (score 6):

As I see from your question you have problems with helicopters(cops being just the same at 3 star level, growing into somewhat of a SWAT team at 4 stars).

What I normally do at 3 stars is the following:

- Lose as many cops as possible
- Get out of the car, take an assault or a sniper rifle
- Take down the helicopter(by killing the driver)
- While there is no other helicopter, run/flee/drive away/whatever from the cops and hide somewhere. Just make sure that a new helicopter won't be able to spot you there(under an overpass for example as [Ryan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/47739/ryan) suggested) and constantly check the radar to make sure that there are no cops around.
- Wait there for a (short) while and drive out as an innocent civillian

With 4 stars the strategy is pretty much the same, but then there comes a SWAT team on SUVs and from a helicopter(so there can be 2 helis at once in the sky). The tactics is pretty much the same, just a bit(lot) more difficult.

Can't say anything about 5 stars yet, didn't do enough crimes to get it :)

Answer (score 6):

My preferred method is to jump onto a moving train as:

- It's always moving and cannot be derailed (As far as I am aware)
- If you manage to get into the flatbed style carriages you can use the edges for cover
- The train often goes under bridges/tunnels which help you evade Helicopters

I've often evaded 5 star wanted levels using this method, however this of course means you are near a train at the time.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do:

If you are planning to get 4~5 stars, try to get a SUV/4x4 or, if you are in downtown Los Santos, a fast car that can climb hills.

Take the nearest highway and go to Banham Canyon or Vinewood Hills or Tataviam Mountains (if you are in Blane County just go to the nearest place that doesn't have roads/dirt roads).

Now get out of the main road and don't get near any dirt roads or beaches and keep driving to any hills that you found. GTA V cops don't follow you there. If doing that you can't dismiss the helicopters, get out of the car and destroy them.

Now the fun part: when your stars start to blink, find a bush, get out of car and hide yourself in a bush (just enter into it) and wait. Cops can't find you in bushes :)

Comment: `Cops can't find you in bushes` - They can ;) It's similar to getting in a new car. They will only see you if they get really close!

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use the "*Burn and Turn*" method:

- Keep an eye on the mini-map and avoid the cops.
- Once you start to pull away, make a turn then floor it for a while.
- Rinse and repeat.

If you get enough space between you can the cars, you can hop out and pick off the helicopter quickly, and return to the *Burn and Turn* method before finding a nice hiding place and sit tight.

Answer (score 1):

Some potential options are:

- Subway Tunnel, Submersible by diving in
- Alamo Sea (works only for 3 STARS) by diving in too
- P-996 Lazer Jet or any plane that is fast enough to quickly fly off and evade the STARS
- tunnel where the soccer ball is located, the tunnel below, and so on and off

I've implemented all of these methods with complete survival and evading of 5 STARS before.  Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  We are a Q&A site, not an outlet for your self-promotion.

Answer (score 0):

These are some tips to avoid the cops.

1. If you find a small alley wait there for 2-5 minutes (only works for 1-2 stars)
2. If you find a train tunnel go in one (only works for 3-5 stars)
3. If you are near a barber or clothes shop go in one of them. (Just make sure you go in there in daytime).

Once I got 4 wanted stars and then there were ninjas (I think?) Hanging from a rope in a helicopter and in 1 shot I was dead. So yeah but the cops given good character to the game but they can be annoying irritating disgusting and boring but when ya gotta deal with them u gotta deal with them. But DO not shoot more than 3 if they are coming Cruz I did that once and like 350 cops came after me and there were 16 dead cops on the floor where I was hiding. Another time was when I was driving around in my OWN car doing nothing and the cops just smacked me out of it. Don't mess with em

Answer (score 0):

Ways to Evade cops in GTA 5

1. Drive down a straight road and lose cops by sheer speed (its possible at 1-3 stars even with chopper)
2. Train tunnels
3. Aircraft (fly at high elevation to prevent choppers getting you)
4. LosSantos Customs (useless if the cops can see you try to go in)
5. Dodge the cops (1-3 stars)
6. Lester (online)

btw guys shooting down a police chopper can get 4 stars if at 3 stars (sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your vehicle
2. Drive down numerous alleys