# Does changing cars while having wanted stars, make it harder for the police to find you?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have noticed that while fleeing from a high wanted level, it is good to use some of [these tactics found here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132029/how-can-i-successfully-evade-the-police-at-higher-wanted-levels), but my friend also mentioned that it is harder for the police to find you if you switch vehicles when you have wanted stars....  Granted - you have to get out of the car, and switch vehicles while they are chasing you, all without being seen doing it (or killing the previous car owner (I would assume)).

I have tried testing this, but at higher wanted levels, the difficulty of this task increases.... Can anyone verify this for me?  *(I also saw someone mentioning it in a comment this on that linked question above - but I am looking for confirmation on the subject)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, changing cars does make it harder for the police to detect you.

If your arrow icon on the minimap turns grey, the police doesn't know that you've changed your vehicle and thus will need to get very close until they can identify you. They *still can* detect you if they get close enough, so having a grey icon doesn't mean you're safe; only that your chances of escaping have greatly improved.

To do this you have to change your vehicle while the police is looking for you, i.e. not chasing you. If you steal your car, chances are high that the police will still know where to look; granted, I never thought about killing the previous owner, but my guess is that if someone witnesses the carjacking, you'll have to kill them as well.

The easiest way to pull off such an escape would be to drive into a parking lot, then steal an unmanned car when the police has lost sight of you. If the alarm goes off, you'll want to avoid the police altogether, at least until the alarm ends.

Comment: additional information: police car will be considered "close enough" when it is in same floor of the carpark. you'd better start moving if you see a police car is moving into carpark. If you're in multi-storey carpark, go to the roof & jump off from the ramp. Higher chance to lose cops, except a police chopper is around.

Comment: Is this true for online mode too? I've noticed when evading the cops that my arrow doesn't ever turn grey, even when switching cars while out of sight. I've done it a hundred times in single player but I can't get it to work in online (though admittedly I have tried only a couple times so far).

Comment: @dpatchery To be honest, I've had plenty of difficulty getting online myself, so I haven't been able to confirm if it works there. I think it should be possible, but I really don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I was able to finally pull this off and noticed that the police couldnt find me when I would drive right past them (when they were looking for me)!

Comment: @dpatchery I think it works differently in GTA Online - police will spot you if you're in a stolen vehicle even if you have no wanted level so I imagine they would spot you more easily if you have switched into another vehicle while wanted. I can only assume that the behaviour is different because in GTA Online you are assumed to be using your personal vehicle most of the time.